# Formula to buy and sell using candlesticks data

Tags: stocks

I was reading/watching videos about how candlesticks in a stock's daily chart can indicate when to buy a stock and when to sell a stock.
The procedure involved analyzing candlesticks and was very lengthy and time consuming.

I was wondering if somebody knew of any math formula that I can use to calculate when to sell or buy stocks; while using the candlestick data.

I ask this because I am very good at math, programming etc.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1570/

Answer (score 1):

If this existed the stock market would be completely different. There are companies that employ hundreds of people that are "really good at math" and they still are lucky if they beat the market.